# Migration from dataSource get the error: Cannot execute operation on "default" connection because connection is not yet established

Tags: typescript, postgresql, typeorm

My typeorm version is 0.3.6.

Whenever i tried to use dataSource.runMigration() i get this error,

```
MIGRATION ERROR:CannotExecuteNotConnectedError: Cannot execute operation on "default" connection because connection is not yet established.
```

i checked the url to migration files, it right. What am i missing?

data-source.ts

```
export const dataSource = new DataSource({
  host:__prod__ ?   process.env.HOST_PROD : process.env.HOST_DEV,
  type: "postgres",
  ...(__prod__
    ? {
        url: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
        username: process.env.PG_USERNAME_PROD,
        password: process.env.PG_PASSWORD_PROD,
        database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME_PROD,
      }
    : {
        username: process.env.PG_USERNAME_DEV,
        password: process.env.PG_PASSWORD_DEV,
        database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME_DEV,
      }),
  ...(__prod__
    ? {
        extra: {
          ssl: {
            rejectUnauthorized: false,
          },
        },
        ssl: true,
      }
    : {}),
  // ...(__prod__ ? {} : { synchronize: true }),
  logging: true,
  entities: [
    Admin,
    ...
  ],
  migrations: [join(__dirname,"/migrations/*")],
});
```

with ***prod*** variable is a boolean variable to check if app in production or not.

And i call it in index.ts

```
try {
    try {
 
       await dataSource.runMigrations();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(`MIGRATION ERROR:${error}`)
    }
    await dataSource.initialize();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`TypeORM STARTING ERROR:${error}`);
  }
```

My file structure

```
server
---dist
------migrations/*.js
      ...
---src
      ...
------migrations/*.ts
```

Comment: It's my understanding that you should be running `initialize` before `runMigrations`...

Answer (score 0):

This could happen because you cannot read from ENV from data-source.ts.
try include  `require("dotenv").config();` at the top of the file. Also, test your configuration by storing it in a const and console log it.

Comment: thanks but i resolved it, just the migration file incorect.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: In my case, my `down` function was empty so it wasn't returning the requisite `Promise<void>`